# Display clock in react.js

Tags: reactjs

I am a beginner in react.js. I wanted to display the clock on my web application, but unfortunately my clock is fixed and does not move forward. What can I do to change the react like this link for a moment, thank you for your help
https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_setinterval2

```
    const setTime = setInterval(time, 1000);
    const event = new Date();
    const time = () => {
        return event.toLocaleTimeString('fa-IR');
    };
```

Comment: Tell me if there is a problem, my answer

Comment: @A.R.SEIF Sorry I'm a beginner, please advise the reason for using this code clearInterval(intervalId);

Comment: yes .If we do not erase `clearInterval`, the effect will remain.this link explane [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-lifecycle-methods-to-a-class)

Comment: @A.R.SEIF Thank you for helping me learn more. Please vote for me if possible

Comment: ok.thanks.@Amir7222

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it isnt working, is the fact that you set `event` to be a specific `new Date()` at the first time the code is ran, and then the interval runs the same function of the exact same date every second. Also, `const` and `let` doesn't support [hoisting](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp), so you should define `time` before setting the interval.

Here is a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-jackson-5fh65?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: This method, which I tried before, gives the following error: Cannot access 'time' before initialization

Comment: Read my answer, I explain it there. One thing is you define the function `time` after you use it inside `setInterval`. The other problem is you're always using the same instance of `new Date()`

Comment: @A.R.SEIF In your example you called `setInterval` everytime that `date` changes, which is not correct.

Comment: Nope, my dependencies array is empty.

Comment: Dear friend, your code was good. Thank you for your participation. Dear friend, you solved my problem. If you have time, thank you for explaining the code. Learn more. @SagiRika

Answer (score 1):

**Code Sample**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Clock = () => {
  const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date().toLocaleTimeString('fa-IR'));

  useEffect(() => {
    document.title = date;
    const timerID = setInterval(() => tick(), 1000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(timerID);
    };
  }, []);

  const tick = () => {
    setDate(new Date().toLocaleTimeString('fa-IR'));
  };

  return <div>{date}</div>;
};

export default Clock;
```

**Working Demo on CodeSandBox**

[image: CodeSandbox]

Comment: why ? What is the problem?

Comment: @Amir7222 .Tell me if there is a problem, otherwise do not forget the vote

Comment: I am testing the code, my friend, if there is a problem, I say thank you for your participation

Comment: You should'nt call `setInterval` every time `date` is changed

Comment: @SagiRika You acted like me.